# Printing IDocument Content upon Start Up

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, startup

I am currently trying to print the contents of an IDocument using `IDocument.get()` upon initiating and running an eclipse plugin, and am running into a wall. I am running the command in the IDocumentSetupParticipant's `setup(IDocument document)` method but am getting an empty string returned (I assume because the text has not yet loaded). In what class and/or method can one call `IDocument.get()` upon startup and get the full document string?
Thanks very much in advance, and do let me know if there are any ambiguities in this question that I could clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IDocumentSetupParticipant` is called before the document's contents are set.

The `IDocument` will fire a `documentChanged` event when its contents are set. So you could add a document listener (using `addDocumentListener`) to the document in the setup participant to get this event.